# how will i create multiple type id in one column database design

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am designing SQL Server database and i have to create multiple FK in one column

so I have these tables and create a menu in one table

```
Table 1             Table 2       Table 3
| Pages            | Jobs         | News
|------------      |---------     |-----------
| Pageid           | Jobid        | NewsId
| PageName         | JobName      | NewsTitle
| MenuName         | MenuName     | MenuName
```

My aim is to reference these table in one column

I have a table from this scenario

```
| MenuGroup
|------------       
| menuGroupId
| MenuName
| RecordeId
```

So how will i achieve the normalize database design?

Comment: Use three different (nullable) columns.

Comment: Go with Tim or use NoSql/Azure where you can have different type in same column. You cannot have it in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sol 1 (Fixed no of Columns):**
This is the most standard and normalized solution. You can create a new table with `nullable columns` as suggested by @Tim

```
| JoiningTable
|------------      
| Id
| PageId
| JobId
| NewsId
```

**Sol2:(Dynamic no of Columns)**:
Although I do not consider it a good approach , since `referential integrity` is lost here, but in case of dynamic number of columns I don't have anyother solution except this one.

```
Type:
|------------      
| TypeId
| Name


JoiningTable
|------------      
| Id
| JoiningId
| TypeId (news,job,pages etc etc)
```

You can compress these  `two` tables into `one` by replacing a `TypeId` with `type` field in `JoiningTable`.

`NoSQl` may also be a solution but I have no experience of working on NOSQL so I cannot recommend you anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you create another table that has the 3 tables' ids as foreign keys then use the primary key of this new table in MenuGroup table and you can use LEFT JOIN to get individual tables through the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple FK's in a single table isn't bad, try using the MenuName column as FK so you won't have to create an extra field in your database.

Comment: As a rule, it's a bad idea to use a string value as a PK or FK. You *can* do it, but you need to make sure that it has a defined length (no `nvarchar(max)`, which is the default for a string with Entity Framework), and you should ensure that the column is indexed. It's far easier and less prone to error to just use an integer.